# How to generate list of random rgb colours

Tags: python

I would like to generate a list of RGB colours. It should be able to generate any colour, but also I want it to be able to generate only either black or white. So, say I have a function `generate_colours(5, True)`

It should return something like `[(0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]`. Then if I did `generate_colours(2, False)` it should return something like `[(211, 18, 5), (20, 30, 194)]`. So the function takes two inputs, the number of colours to generate and a boolean as to whether or not it should generate only black/white.

I am trying to do this in Python, and this is my solution so far which only works for black/white and isn't very efficient:

```
import numpy as np


def generate_colours(pixel_amount):
    random_numbers = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=pixel_amount)
    generated_colours = []
    for number in random_numbers:
        if number == 0:
            generated_colours.append((0, 0, 0))
        else:
            generated_colours.append((255, 255, 255))
    return generated_colours
```

EDIT: I think I need to do something like `random_numbers = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(pixel_amount, 3))`. However, I can't figure out how to make it only generate `(255, 255, 255)` or `(0, 0, 0)` and I want it to generate a list of tuples rather than `[[229 17 25] [65 129 126] ... ]`.

EDIT: I believe I have solved it, however I think my implementation is rather inefficient and since I am going to be running this function a LOT, I would really appreciate some help making it better.

```
import numpy as np


def generate_colours(pixel_amount, black_and_white):
    if black_and_white:
        random_numbers = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=pixel_amount)
        generated_colours = []
        for number in random_numbers:
            if number == 0:
                generated_colours.append((0, 0, 0))
            else:
                generated_colours.append((255, 255, 255))
    else:
        random_numbers = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(pixel_amount, 3))
        generated_colours = [tuple(colour) for colour in random_numbers.tolist()]
    return generated_colours
```

Comment: How do you want to decide how many black vs. how many white pixels it should return?

Comment: @atru it should be random

Comment: In your all-colours example, defining `generated_colours` takes about 13 times longer than just defining `random_numbers`; perhaps you can change your downstream code so it can just use an `np.ndarray` rather than a list of tuples?

Comment: You can also use parallel processing, simple analog of a parallel for loop for instance. It's straightforward with Python's [multiprocessing toolbox](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) but it's feasibility will depend on the rest of the code and requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to improve it is using list comprehension in the black and white case:

```
def generate_colours(pixel_amount, black_and_white):
    if black_and_white:
        random_numbers = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=pixel_amount)
        generated_colours = [(0, 0, 0) if number == 0 else (255, 255, 255) for number in random_numbers ]
    else:
        random_numbers = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(pixel_amount, 3))
        generated_colours = [tuple(colour) for colour in random_numbers.tolist()]
    return generated_colours
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve this part. However, I would also like to then use PIL to construct an image from the generated pixels. I tried `new_image = Image.fromarray(generated_colours)`, `new_image.save("new.png", "PNG")`. However, I get an error https://pastebin.com/QCXNQsf8. I think it's because I need to tell it the dimensions but I don't know how.

Comment: Or perhaps I should just write some code to change it from 784 lots of (r, g, b) to 28 lots of 28 (r, g, b).